# Can I accomplish css transform rotateY effects in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I want to have a circle rotate according to its y-axis, like using rotateY in CSS.

I have looked up the document, I noticed the transform function:
http://bucephalus.org/text/CanvasHandbook/CanvasHandbook.html#transform-a-b-c-d-e-f

but I have no idea how to calculate the variable or I need a 3D library?

Any help is thankful.

Comment: You can simulate rotateY by drawing an [ellipse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse) instead of a circle and changing the `radiusX`

Comment: @enxaneta good idea, I will try it.